# Set to false flexslider slide animation only when under 780px screen width

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, flexslider

Quick little question:

How can I disable the slide animation on flexslider ONLY when under 780px screen width?

Any clever easy javascript I can add?

Possibly target the slideshow: true only when in that specific screen size?

Thanks in advance and good day everyone ^.^

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,
            slideshow: true               
        });

   });
```

Maybe adding something like:

```
  $(window).width(780) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            slideshow: false

        });
```

but the above attempt seems incorrect. If anyone could share some light <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) for this and set up a listener for when the screen size moves above/below the 780px threshold.

```
var query = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 780px)");
query.addListener(mediaChange);

function mediaChange(query) {
  if(query.matches) {
    //We are 780px or below, disable flexslider animation
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshow: false});
  } else {
    //We are above 780px, enable flexslider animation
    $('.flexslider').flexslider({slideshow: true});
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Im going to mark this correct because it worked, but I solved my issue in a different way. I ended up not having to disable it for mobile, but at first your answer did work for what I asked!